# Load Persistence.xml from environment

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'd like to deploy my application on multiple servers. Those servers have different database-managers. (one is Oracle, the other is Postgres in this case).

These require different persistence unit configurations, because Hibernate needs the dialect defined for Oracle, but then the Postgres db won't work. Sadly, by not configuring the dialect in the `persistence.xml`, Hibernate is unable to auto-detect the Oracle dialect.

Is there a way to define the persistence unit configuration for the environment?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1990914/2849346 => "Data Source" via JNDI.

Comment: I know how to get a datasource via JNDI. I need the Persistence Unit itself. A rough example: something like getting the persistence.xml from JNDI would be a good solution

Comment: Have you tried the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.persistenceXmlLocation` property?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this bean is only available in Spring. I'm working in java enterprise edition as the tag suggests

Comment: You can define multiple persistence units in one `persistence.xml`, and choose which one to launch when calling `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory`

Comment: I'd like a more general solution, where the environment knows the database configuration. Similar, to how JNDI Datasources work, but a bit more abstract

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a means by which to configure Hibernate Dialect Based on jta-data-source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962519/is-there-a-means-by-which-to-configure-hibernate-dialect-based-on-jta-data-sourc)

Comment: see my edit, sadly this solution doesn't work